# How to fix "Run-time error '1004'" cause by Target.Formula function

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file where I want to check if cell "$A$2" is empty and if that's true I want to add the formula `(=VLOOKUP($I$2;'Raw Data'!$A$1:$AH$5000;4;FALSE)` in this cell. Went I run the code below it generates a

> Run-tim error '1004' (Application-defined or object defined error).

I already played with the target formula and if I take simple formulas like `=B1+B2` it works and I don^t get an error message. So it seems to be something about the Vlookup formula that causes the error.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If (Target.Cells.Address = "$A$2" And Target = vbNullString) Then
        Target.Formula = "=VLOOKUP($I$2;'Raw Data'!$A$1:$AH$5000;4;FALSE)"
    End If
End Sub
```

I expect the cell `"$A$2"` to show the result of the formula `=VLOOKUP($I$2;'Raw Data'!$A$1:$AH$5000;4;FALSE)` unless the cell is overwritten manually.

Thanks for your help @Pᴇʜ @eirikduade @Gareth!

Now I am trying to do the same for all cells in Column A where there is a value in column I of the same row and I struggle with the .Range function. Could you please give me any suggestions how to fix the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim lastRowF As Integer
    lastRowF = Sheet3.Cells(Sheet3.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
    For j = 1 To lastRowF
        If Intersect(Target, Me.Range(Cells(j, 2))) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        If Me.Range(.Cells(j, 2)) = vbNullString Then
            Me.Range(.Cells(j, 2)).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(""" & cells.(y, 1) & """,'Raw Data'!$A$1:$AH$5000,4,FALSE)"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The main issue

You need to switch the `;` to `,` because the `.Formula` needs to be the original english version of the formula which uses `,`.

#### Your code will fail if `Target` is a range of multiple cells

Note that your code will fail if you eg. copy paste a range (not a single cell).

Change it to the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A2")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error Goto ENABLE_EVENTS

    If Me.Range("A2").Value = vbNullString Then
        Me.Range("A2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP($I$2,'Raw Data'!$A$1:$AH$5000,4,FALSE)"
    End If

ENABLE_EVENTS:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
End Sub
```

---

If you need to do it for multiple cells in column A it would look like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim AffectedRange As Range
    Set AffectedRange = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A2:A" & Me.Rows.Count))

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error Goto ENABLE_EVENTS

    If Not AffectedRange Is Nothing Then
        Dim iCell As Range
        For Each iCell In AffectedRange.Cells
            If iCell.Value = vbNullString Then
                iCell.Formula = "=VLOOKUP($I" & iCell.Row & ",'Raw Data'!$A$1:$AH$5000,4,FALSE)"
            End If
        Next iCell
    End If

ENABLE_EVENTS:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
End Sub
```

Note that you probably mean to use

```
"=VLOOKUP($I" & iCell.Row & ", 'Raw Data'!$A$1:$AH$5000,4,FALSE)"
```

instead of

```
"=VLOOKUP($I$2, 'Raw Data'!$A$1:$AH$5000,4,FALSE)"
```

Comment: Works so far but I need to add another row that checks if there is a value in column I. Cause if there is no value in column I the code creates an error. Can you help with this one?

Comment: You can use `Me.Cells(iCell.Row, "I").Value` to access the value in the same row in column I. Use that to buid your check `If iCell.Value = vbNullString And Me.Cells(iCell.Row, "I").Value <> vbNullString Then`. Also note that I added `Application.EnableEvents = False` incuding error handling which is necessary to avoid that writing to the cell triggers another change event (I forgot that).

Answer (score 0):

In VBA code, you must use commas to separate arguments in functions, even if your local delimiter is semi-colons.

I.e. change the line

```
Target.Formula = "=VLOOKUP($I$2;'Raw Data'!$A$1:$AH$5000;4;FALSE)"
```

to

```
Target.Formula = "=VLOOKUP($I$2,'Raw Data'!$A$1:$AH$5000,4,FALSE)"
```

and see if that works